# Lebesgue-integral of a sum

Tags: measure-theory

Why can I conclude that the follwing holds:

$$ \int_X f^+ d\mu + \int_X f^- d\mu = \int_X |f| d\mu$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For nonnegative simple functions the integral is additive. Let $(g_n)$ and $(h_n)$ be sequences of nonnegative simple functions increasing to $f^{+}$ and $f^{-}$ respectively. Then $g_n+h_n$ increases to $f^{+}+f^{-}=|f|$. So take limit in $\int (g_n+h_n)=\int g_n +\int h_n$ to finish the proof.

Comment: The problem is to understand why $f^++f^-=|f|$ Might be simple?

Comment: For ant real number $x$ the equation $|x|=x^{+}+x^{-}$ holds because this reduces to $x=x+0$ when $x \geq 0$ and $-x=0-x$ when $x<0$.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Essential for understanding this is the fact that for nonnegative measurable functions $g,h$ we have the equality:$$\int(g+h) =\int g+\int h\tag1$$

Applying this on $g=f^+$ and $h=f^-$ we find:$$\int|f|=\int (f^++f^-)=\int f^++\int f^-$$

The equality $(1)$ is a *cornerstone* of measure theory. The proof of it starts by showing that is it is true for simple functions. Then it can be extended by using the fact that for a measurable nonnegative function $f$ we have by definition: $$\int f=\sup\left(\left\{\int g\mid g\text{ is a measurable simple function with }0\leq g\leq f\right\}\right)$$